# Calculating limits using the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Suppose you have a function $f(x)=\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}$.

How then do we find the limit as $x\to2$ in accordance with the $\epsilon-\delta$ definition? I mean suppose we don't know how to calculate the limit and we have to derive a method to calculate the limit using $\epsilon-\delta$ definition of limit. Then what intuition will be used to derive it and what will be the value?

Comment: This is exactly the sort of situation in which a live one-on-one instructor is far superior to on-line questioning.

Comment: The first idea would be to set $x = 2+h$ and see where that takes you.

Comment: I always thought $\varepsilon -\delta$ was for intuition verification and not the other way around.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We should have $$\epsilon>\left|\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}-l\right|=\left|x+2-l\right|,$$

for some $\delta>0$ and any $\delta>|x-2|>0$.

This is equivalent to say that the set of solutions of this last inequality must be contained in the set of solutions of the former for each $\epsilon$ and some $\delta=\delta_\epsilon$. So, we just need to solve both inequalities and impose this condition.

So we get $$\epsilon-2+l>x>l-2-\epsilon,$$ as the solution of the first inequality.

And  $\delta+2>x>2-\delta$, $x\neq0$, for the other inequality.

Forcing that one set is inside the other we get

$$[\epsilon+l-2,l-2-\epsilon]\supset[\delta+2,2-\delta]$$

Since this is for any $\epsilon$ (well, it is enough to impose it for $\epsilon=1/n$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$), and some $\delta=\delta_\epsilon$ we need to find the intersection of all the intervals $[\frac{1}{n}+l-2,l-2-\frac{1}{n}]$. This is easy in this case. It is the number $l-2$. In fact, notice $l-2$ is inside all these intervals and that if we take any other number, $l-2+t$, we can find some of those intervals in which $l-2+t$ is outside by taking $n>|1/t|$.

Then, since the corresponding intervals $[\delta_n+2,2-\delta_n]$ should be inside the $[l-2+\frac{1}{n},l-2-\frac{1}{n}]$, and the intersections of the former for all $\delta_n$, is $2$, then the intersections must coincide.

We get then $l-2=2$, from where $l=4$.

**In general:**
For the limit $$\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f(x)$$

One must solve the inequality $\epsilon>|f(x)-l|$ and the inequality $\delta>|x-a|>0$ (separately) and impose the set of solutions of the latter is inside the set of solutions of the former. Then impose this condition for every $\epsilon>0$ and some $\delta=\delta_\epsilon$ (it usually involves intersecting many intervals and it is enough to do it for $\epsilon=1/n$, for $n\in\mathbb{N}$).

Comment: Can you explain what did you do after           ϵ + l − 2 ≥ δ + 2 > 2 − δ ≥ l − 2 − ϵ .

Comment: That is a key question. And is one of the reasons why computing limits this way is not effective in general. I will add more detail. The other reason is that solving the inequalities might be hard in general.

Comment: Then please can you explain what other method can be sed to compute limit effectively and why that method works and how does it give correct answers ?

Comment: Wow! That would require writing a chapter from a book. Any book in calculus has a chapter about it. The technique is a tabular method. You compute a few, very simple limits like this, or even simpler, by this method and put them in a small table. Then you prove general properties of the $\lim$. Finally you reduce the computation of harder limits to the ones in the table by using the properties of limits.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\,\epsilon >0\,$ be arbitrary. Since $\,x\to 2\,$ we are very close to $\,2\,$ but *not equal* to $\,2\,$, and then

$$\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=\frac{(x-2)(x+2)}{x-2}=x+2\;,\;\;x\ne 2$$

and from here that the wanted limit is $\,4\;$ . Thus:

$$\left|\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}-4\right|=|x+2-4|=|x-2|$$

then, our choice for $\;\delta\;$ is pretty simple: choose $\,|x-2|<\delta:=\epsilon\;$ and we're done...

Comment: I think the OP wants to know how to find the limit using the definition, I mean actually finding it, prior to suspecting it is $2$.

Comment: I think that's practically impossible in the general case, @GitGud , and this is something that is usually explained to first year undergraduate students, i believe. Anyway, in this particular case, after the cancellation it is pretty straightforward the limit is $\,4\,$.

Comment: I think he only took this function as an example. Let's  wait for the OP to make it clear what he wants.

Comment: you just proved that the limit is 4 you didnt mke use of epsilon delta to explain why it was 4 ? This function is only an example i wanted to know how would you derive a method to find the value of limit by just knowing the epsilon delta defination

Comment: @austin, I don't think there's a general method to calculate the limit only using epsilon-delta...in fact, I don't think there's even a practical general method to find out whether the limit even exists ( finitely or not).

Answer (score 0):

To answer the OP's question: "Then please can you explain what other method can be sed to compute limit effectively and why that method works and how does it give correct answers?", since he included "infinitesimals" among the tags, I would elaborate on @Daniel Fischer's comment above and set $x=2+h$ where $h\not=0$ is infinitesimal.  Then the limit can be calculated "effectively" (or more precisely "directly") as follows:
$$\frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=x+2,$$
therefore
$$\lim \frac{x^2-4}{x-2}=\lim x+2=\text{st}(2+h+2)=4+\text{st}(h)=4+0=4,$$
since by definition of an infinitesimal the standard part "st" satisfies $\text{st}(h)=0$.  Here one does not need to know what happens for every epsilon, and needn't bother with choosing a delta, in accordance with the OP's request "Then what intuition will be used to derive it and what will be the value ?"