# how to demonstrate that $\lim_{x\to2}3x^2=12$ using $\gamma$ and $\epsilon$ definition

Tags: calculus, limits, proof-writing, epsilon-delta

**how to demonstrate that $\lim_{x\to2}3x^2=12$ using $\gamma$ and $\epsilon$ definition?**

*My current steps I have in order from top to bottom:*

$|3x^2-12|<\epsilon$ and $0<|x-2|<\gamma$

assume $z=x-2$

$0<|z|<\gamma$ and $3z^2+12|z|<\epsilon$

$3z^2+12|z|<3\gamma^2+12\gamma=3\gamma(4+\gamma)$

Then assume $\gamma<1$

$\gamma=15$ hence $\gamma=\frac{\epsilon}{15}$

then now i am stuck and have no clue how to proceed

Comment: Hmmm, never heard of a gamma/epsilon proof. Isn't it usually delta/epsilon? Anyway, your first sentence of your proof should probably be something like "Let epsilon be a positive real number." It's very important to realize that a proof is a verbal argument. It consists of full sentences arranged in paragraphs. It's an explanation, an argument. Very different from the math you have done before. It's not just a series of equations and inequalities.

Comment: How do you get $3z^2+12|z|<\epsilon$? What exactly happens after you get $3\gamma(4+\gamma)$? Steps should be written out clearly.

Comment: Also, you can't start talking about variable until they are introduced. If I read your first line I would say "Really? How do you know the absolute value of 3x^2 - 12 is less than epsilon, and how do you know the absolute value of x - 2 is less than gamma? I wouldn't be able to judge because you haven't told me what x, epsilon, and delta are." Read one of the proofs in your textbook very closely and see how all the variables are introduced. Also make sure you understand the definition of a limit before writing a proof.

Comment: See [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/458116/92427) as an example. The key point, I would say, for this kind of problem is to find $\delta$ (what you are calling $\gamma$) as a function of $\epsilon$.

Comment: To strict you should also handle the case $\epsilon > 15$ (the definition says that *for all $\epsilon > 0$* we can find a $\gamma > 0$  such that...). In this case $\gamma = 1$ works.

Comment: Why do you say $\gamma = 15$ and then completely contradict yourself and so $\gamma = \frac \epsilon {15}$?  Unless $\frac \epsilon{15} = 15$ these are contradictory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay,  let's just say that everything you've done is scratch paper.  You have reached the conclusion $\delta$ should be $ \frac {\epsilon}{15}$ and $\delta < 1$.  So know we need to turn this into a proof.

For any $\epsilon > 0$, we can define $\delta = \min (1, \frac {\epsilon}{15})$.

Now for any $x$  so that $|x-2| < \delta$ (that is to say for any $x \in (2-\delta, 2+ \delta)$ then

$-\delta < x- 2< \delta$

$0 < 2 - \delta < x < 2 + \delta$

$(2-\delta)^2 < x^2 < (2+\delta)^2$

$4 - 4\delta + \delta^2 < x^2 <4\delta + \delta^2$.

$-4\delta + \delta^2 < x^2 - 4 <  4 \delta + \delta^2$.

Now as $\delta \le 1$ we know $\delta^2 \le \delta$ and so

$-5\delta < -4\delta + \delta^2 < x^2 - 4 < 4 \delta + \delta^2 < 5\delta$

$-15\delta < 3x^2 - 12 < 15\delta$

$|3x^2 -12| < 15\delta$.

So $\delta \le \frac {\epsilon}{15}$ then

$|3x^2 - 12| < 15\delta \le 15\frac {\epsilon}{15}=\epsilon$.

And that is the definition of $\lim_{x\to 2} 3x^2 = 2$.

(I do advise rereading the definition and understanding what it *means*:

(That is for *ANY* small distance $\epsilon > 0$ no matter how small, we can *determine* that there is some distance $\delta > 0$ so then *whenever* we can choose *ANY* $x$ within $\delta$ of $2$, that is to say, if $|x -2| < \delta$, we will then know that it *MUST* also be that $3x^2$ is within $\epsilon$ of $12$.  That is $|3x^2 - 12| < \epsilon$.)

Comment: question- if $\delta$ is less than or equal to 1 couldnt 4+$4\delta$ be greater than 5$\delta$?\

Comment: $4 < 4 + 4\delta < 8$ and $5\delta < 5$.  But that doesn't have anything to do with anything.

Answer (score 0):

Let $|x-2|\lt 1$ , then

$-1<x-2<1$, or $3<x +2<5$.

$|3x^2-12| = 3|x-2||x+2|$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given.

Choose $ \delta = \min (1,\epsilon/(15))$.

Then $|x-2| \lt \delta$ implies

$3|x-2||x+2| \lt $

$(3)(5)|x-2| \lt (15)\delta \lt \epsilon$.

Answer (score 0):

What you have given is sometimes called a "synthetic" proof- you start with what you want to prove, $|3x^2- 12|< \epsilon$, and arrive at $\gamma\le \frac{\epsilon}{15}$.  Of course, you **can't** prove something by assuming it is true!  This is, still, a valid proof because every step is *reversible*.  That is, the "real proof" starts by taking $\gamma$ to be any number less than $\frac{\epsilon}{15}$ then works backwards to $|3x^2- 12|< \epsilon$.

Comment: I would strongly disagree with your first sentence. What I am reading is not close to any type of proof at all. It is all just nonsense. For example, the first sentence makes a claim about variables that haven't been quantified over or given any values. So we can't even judge the first sentence.